# Filter video list by tag

Tags: youtube-data-api

**Goal**
Get videos, ordered by date, and filtered by tag from a specific YouTube channel. I need only the videos that have that unique tag. I understand I can get the latest uploaded videos, then one by one query YouTube API for each video and determine if it has the tags I need. But I find that too lengthy and wonder if there's a single API request than can handle that filter for me.

**Tried**

Reading this [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) I understood the *snippet* was supposed to have a *snippet.tags*:

> snippet.tags[]
>
> **list**
>
> A list of keyword tags associated with the video. Tags may contain spaces. The property value has a maximum length of 500 characters. Note the following rules regarding the way the character limit is calculated:
>   The property value is a list, and commas between items in the list count toward the limit.
>   If a tag contains a space, the API server handles the tag value as though it were wrapped in quotation marks, and the quotation marks count toward the character limit. So, for the purposes of character limits, the tag Foo-Baz contains seven characters, but the tag Foo Baz contains nine characters.

Using the [following](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) (search/list)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=CHANNEL_ID&maxResults=10&order=date&type=video&key=MY_GOOGLE_CONSOLE_KEY
```

I get:

```
    {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/MO86DiShKKJ483oXkFJdDmvBd5M\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "jMywJTXhkVs"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-09-16T15:28:40.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4GRKWUEhUvsCqD-yNQpxQw",
    "title": "Real Time - Gesture Drawing 7 (5.10 mins time)",
    "description": "Join me in gesture drawing practice from photo reference. :) References (in order of drawing) - Thank you to SenshiStock (https://senshistock.deviantart.com/) ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jMywJTXhkVs/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jMywJTXhkVs/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jMywJTXhkVs/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Chayemor",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
```

The **snippet** only includes `publishedAt`, `channelId`, `title`, and `description`, certainly no `tags`.

Looking into **/search/list** [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) I see that it has another parameter that I might be able to use:

> **q**
>
> **string**
>
> The q parameter specifies the query term to search for.
>
> Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to
>   exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of
>   several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching
>   either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to
>   boating|sailing. Similarly, to search for videos matching either
>   "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter value to
>   boating|sailing -fishing. Note that the pipe character must be
>   URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value
>   for the pipe character is %7C.

So I use the tag "**sketching**" that I know is set in various videos. (A way to determine if a single video's tags is through `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=GOOGLE_KEY&fields=items(snippet(title,description,tags))&part=snippet&id=video_id` )

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=%22sketching%22&part=snippet&channelId=CHANNEL_ID&maxResults=25&order=date&type=video&key=GOOGLE_KEY
```

That yields this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/hPC7YXbOHVWNEk_6UiC5Jzdh5Zs\"",
 "regionCode": "ES",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 10,
  "resultsPerPage": 25
 },
 "items": []
}
```

Nothing else. It says there are **10** results, but I don't see them, I do't know what they are. I tried sending the request without the "" but it returned the same result. Messing around I saw that when searching within a channel's videos from YouTube (as a browser client, through GUI, not API), it uses the parameter **'query'**. So out of not having any more ideas I decided to substitute `q` for `query`.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?query=sketching&part=snippet&channelId=UC4GRKWUEhUvsCqD-yNQpxQw&maxResults=25&order=date&type=video&key=GOOGLE_KEY
```

That query did yield results, but not of those videos who had that unique tag, but rather any video that had that tag or that word used in the title or description.

```
    {
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"cbz3lIQ2N25AfwNr-BdxUVxJ_QY/xjWZRnm0X7B_csQX4KEu9nv_qdQ\"",
 "regionCode": "ES",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 24,
  "resultsPerPage": 25
 },
 "items": [ ... ] 
}
```

Any suggestions?